# Apache Hive regEx serde: data types

Tags: regex, apache, hive

For processing logs I want to use Apache Hive regEx serde but I only found examples that use String as datatype for the columns of the table.

Now my question is: are datebased types and integers and arrays supported or is it just strings?

This example (and others) only uses strings:

```
CREATE TABLE access_log (
  remote_ip STRING,
  request_date STRING,
  method STRING,
  request STRING,
  protocol STRING
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.serde2.RegexSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES  (
"input.regex" = "([^ ]) . . [([^]]+)] \"([^ ]) ([^ ]) ([^ \"])\" *",
"output.format.string" = "%1$s %2$s %3$s %4$s %5$s"
)
STORED AS TEXTFILE
```

;

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Refer the code of SERDE : [code of RegexSerDe](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/org/apache/hadoop/hive/contrib/serde2/RegexSerDe.java.html) or [github - RegexSerDe code](https://github.com/apache/hive/blob/trunk/contrib/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/hive/contrib/serde2/RegexSerDe.java),
  All columns have to be of type STRING. -- from  program comment
- If you want to do some tweak to it, write some custom Serde code(if you are good at java , then proceed ) and add as a  custom serde jar   like this example [csv custom serde](https://github.com/ogrodnek/csv-serde/)
- If not, let the columns type be STRING only, and when you want to act upon any column use   Casting ( **cast() function in hive**  )  in query.

hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks for the decent info :)

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used the RegexSerDe personally, but I do notice that there are two classes for it:
[serde/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/hive/serde2/RegexSerDe.java](https://github.com/apache/hive/blob/trunk/serde/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/hive/serde2/RegexSerDe.java)
[contrib/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/hive/contrib/serde2/RegexSerDe.java](https://github.com/apache/hive/blob/trunk/contrib/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/hive/contrib/serde2/RegexSerDe.java)

The second one, which you are referring to, does indeed appear to be restricted to strings. The other appears to support primitive types.

For whatever reason I only see the second one referenced in the [API docs](http://hive.apache.org/javadocs/r0.12.0/api/).

Comment: @VeLKerr's comment: In addition to the ahains's answer (unfortunately, I haven't enough reputation to comment yet)... The first Regexp doesn't supports serialization (only deserialization).