# log file parsing in hcatalog regex or serde

Tags: hadoop, hcatalog

I am pretty new to Hadoop.

I am trying to load my log file into HCatalog. The following is the format of my log file.

```
Time: 2014-10-28 06:32:34Z
UserID: arun
GroupID: admin
Page: welcome.aspx
Message: Login successful

Time: 2014-10-28 06:32:34Z
UserID: arun
GroupID: admin
Page: main.aspx
Message: menu load
..
..
```

Do I need to write a SerDe to parse this or can this be achieved via regex?

Answer (score 0):

I belive you would like to load the external log files into Hive tables wherein the Hive metastore is managed by the HCatalog service.

If so, First analyze the source log records for a fixed delimiter which will help Hive to parse the records into required n number of columns, mostly the tab (\t) char will help.

The next option could be achieving the column parsing from the source log records using the Hive RegexSerDe class with the relevant regular expression.

If the regex parsing is not feasible then the other option is to create custom hive serde class to parse the source log file  records . With the help of the custom serde class,  Hive will be able to perfectly fit the delimited cells into the relevant columns of the Hive external table.

Please refer,

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/gettingstarted/latest/emr/getting-started-emr-load-data.html

[Apache Hive regEx serde: data types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21342510/apache-hive-regex-serde-data-types)

http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2012/12/how-to-use-a-serde-in-apache-hive/